# Javascript/ Facebox getElementById not returning anything

Tags: javascript, html, css, getelementbyid, facebox

I am opening up a small modal dialog using facebox with a form and then trying to access the value inside a text field on that form with javascript. This is the HTML code -

```
<div id="dialog-form95" style="display:none">
<div class="block">
  <form action="" method="post" name="form95">
    <h3>Setting URL</h3>
    <p></p>
    <p><label>URL : </label></p><input type="text" class="text" id="du95" name="url"/>
    <p><input type="submit" class="submit small" value="save" onclick="updateUrl(95,109); return false;"/></p>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the javascript onclick -

```
function updateUrl(bid, cid){
    alert(document.getElementById('du'+bid).value);
}
```

I even tried hardcoding "du95". Whenever i update anything in the textbox and submit, it shows a blank alert dialog. Nothing shows up in the js console as well.

Answer (score 1):

That's because it has no value. Try and see what happens:

```
 <input type="text" class="text" id="du95" name="url" value="testing" />
```

Comment: Yes, now it will alert "testing" but not the field value if i change it.

Comment: it alerts "testing" even if i edit it. I need to take the field value for js processing

Comment: It shouldn't continue to alert "testing" once you change the value. Make sure you're changing the value *before* the javascript fires.

Comment: yep. Even if i change the value in the field and click the save button it alerts "testing"

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you have `display: none` in you container div.

After removing that it seems to work fine in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8bSdK/

Comment: Yup, seems you are right. But need an intermediate solution because it is a modal dialog which pops up from another button. So it has to be display:none until another script displays it.